# Discord.py check if user is friend in on_member_update

Tags: python, discord.py

i trying to make a Stalk bot (I know discord automisation bots are forbidden)
But it dont really "Automise your bot"
Sooooo i need to know how i check if user is friend in on_member_update event. i already tried

if before.is_friend() == True:

if after.is_friend() == True:

if discord.User.is_friend() == True:

But all of them didnt really work out. So maybe you have a Idea why

Answer (score 0):

The way I would recommend is checking if your specific user is in the bot's friends list.

```
if member in client.user.friends:
    print("{} is on my friends list!".format(member.name))
```

Comment: It should work as long as you define `member` as the member class that is being updated.